# How can I find if an id has a specific string ??? (Prototype)

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Like http://bit.ly/ideYPm, i need change this:

```
function createPickers() { 
    $(document.body).select('input.datepicker').each( function(e) {     
        new Control.DatePicker(e, { 'locale': 'pt_BR'}); 
    } ); 
} 
Event.observe(window, 'load', createPickers);
```

To get "inputs" with "Data" (date in portuguese) string in **id**, like:

```
<input type="text" id="EntradaEquipamentoDataEntrada"></input>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a wildcard like:

```
$$('input[id*="Data"]')
```

so your code would look more like:

```
function createPickers() { 
    $$('input[id*="Data"]').each( function(e) {     
        new Control.DatePicker(e, { 'locale': 'pt_BR'}); 
    } ); 
} 
Event.observe(window, 'load', createPickers);
```

Comment: ops..only forgot the "." to .each(

Comment: edited the answer to reflect the proper framework. Im always mixing them up.

Comment: please add the first $ to $$ as well. Otherwise great!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="EntradaEquipamentoDataEntrada"></input>

//Assuming datepicker has been assigned
var id  = $('input.datepicker').readAttribute('id');

var checker = id.indexOf('Entrada'); 
//returns index of first match start position
//returns -1 if no matches found
```

use `lastIndexOf()` to find last match